# Codeigniter - Can't load data into header or footer

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm fairly new to Codeigniter and I'm having an issue loading data into the header and footer. I've used this code in another controller which works, but does not work when sending to header or footer.

**Controller (Attempt):**

```
public function loadSettings() {
    $settings = $this->settingmodel->getSetting();
    $data = (array) $settings[0];

    $this->load->view('header', $data);
  }
```

**Working Controller:**

```
public function index() {

    if ($this->session->userdata('logdinUser')) {

        $sessionArray = $this->session->userdata('logdinUser');

        if ($sessionArray['type'] == USERTYPE_PLAYER)

            redirect(site_url('player'), 'refresh');

        if ($sessionArray['type'] == USERTYPE_PROFESSOR)

            redirect(site_url('game'), 'refresh');

        if ($sessionArray['type'] == USERTYPE_ADMIN)

            redirect(site_url('admin'), 'refresh');
    }

    $admin = $this->settingmodel->getSetting();
    $settings = (array) $admin[0];

    $this->load->view('user/index', $settings);
}
```

**Model Called:**

```
public function saveSetting($array, $id = false) {
      $setting['environment'] = $array['environment'];
      $setting['analytics'] = $array['analytics'];
        $setting['email'] = $array['email_id'];
        $setting['paypal_amount'] = $array['paypal_amount'];
        $setting['paypal_type'] = $array['paypal_type'];
        $setting['paypal_currency'] = $array['paypal_currency'];
        $insertedid=$id;

      if ($id)
            $updated = $this->mongo_db->where('_id', new MongoId($id))->set($setting)->update($this->table_name);
      else
          $insertedid=$this->mongo_db->insert($this->table_name, $setting);
        return $insertedid;

    }

    function getSetting() {
        $query = $this->mongo_db->get($this->table_name);
        return $query;
    }
```

**In View:**

```
echo $environment;
```

Answer (score 0):

I 'm doing like this

I have created  common `layout.php` file in  `root` of the `view folder` and i load to all content to that file.I include   `java script and css` file and common `ajax /jquery` code to my layout file

```
<html>
 <head> 

        <title> </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
         <!-- include common css/js in here --> 

 </head>
<body>
  <div class="panel-body">
     <!--load your content to here.-->
     <?php echo $content; ?> 

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can call form Controller like this.

```
function home() {

    $data['other_data'] = $this->other_model->other_data();
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('home/content', $data, true);
    $this->load->view('layout', $data);

}
```

Comment: Seems the common recommendation, is this something that will take a lot of work to configure. I'm trying to see how I will not have to go through like 30 view files to re-configure the entire app to use this one layout file.